# Sortable.js Bugs when using in Swiper.js

Tags: swiper.js

When using a sortable.js List in a Swiper.js Instance, manipulating the list wont work anymore.

I've tried to set

```
swiper.noSwiping = true;
```

But the bug stays the same. Here is a Codepen that let's you easily reproduce the problem.

https://codepen.io/fabuchao/pen/wxeXMe

Answer (score 1):

I found out that

```
swiper.allowTouchMove = false;
```

fixes the problem. You need to change slides via the swiper api afterwards.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue, this fixed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me.

I added drag-handles on the sortable divs, with a class 'handle'.
And then, I added the following option during swiper initialization:

```
noSwipingClass: 'handle',
```

Now both the swiping & sorting work, flawlessly.

allowTouchMove: false -
also works, but that disables the swiping.